# Emit particles as vertices and then creating a convex hull out of this

Tags: particles

I would need to convert the particles which I emit to vertices. Then I can select all vertices and create a new object with a convex hull. This would be really interesting but I can't find a way to convert the created particles to vertices. Any idea?

Comment: This add-on could be worth a shot, it allows users to connect particles together. It says on the page that inside the next update it will be able to link particles with polygons. https://blendermarket.com/products/ik-particles-link

Comment: Animation Nodes may be the way to go. See related question https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/97095/29586. The comments mention creating a convex hull - although the answer is different - but may be close to what you're looking for.