# Network animation with faces / simplicial complex using animation nodes

Tags: node-editor, particles, animation-nodes, topology, dynamic-topology

I am looking for a way to quickly and automatically construct an animation of a type of network (called a simplicial complex) wherein sections of the network structure have material on the faces in between the vertices.  I can construct the animation of a network using the 'animation nodes' package, here: https://animation-nodes.com/

This package allows the vertices to 'connect' or draw and edge between them whenever a certain criteria is met, such as the distance between them is below a threshold.

However, I have not figured out how to include a face on the triangle between nodes if the vertices are all connected to each other.

Here is an example of a snapshot in the animation of a simplicial complex (I would like for the vertices to move and faces to respond by appearing/disappearing with the edges in the animation):

[image]

This gif describes the type of motion:

[image]

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

This answer is based on [Omar Emara's Answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/97475/105501)
, so be sure to read it before you move on as I won't explain everything that have been answered there.
This is the loop to generate polygon

[image: Original Answers]

However, this loop doesn't take the distances between vertex points into account so I modify the loop to use the *Distances* output from *Find Nearest Points* node. As per [documentation](https://docs.animation-nodes.com/documentation/nodes/tree/find_nearest_points/)

> **Distances** - The distances between the output points and the input point.

Input point is the inputs *Vector*, this outputs give you a list of floating point (the distances) with length same as *Amount* input where the first element is always zero as it is the distance to itself. With that we can compare each value with distance threshold.

```
not any(set(p) == polygon for p in polygons) and all(d < radius for d in distances)
```

`radius` is the distance threshold. `all(d < radius for d in distances)` will make sure that every value is inside the radius or below the threshold.
You can see where each node connecting to what node. Put that code on *Expression* node.

[image: Create Polygon Loop]

By adding this new condition input in generator, we only add polygon indices that met certain distance threshold. You can ignore the *Distances List* output of the loop for now. Here is the comparison side-by-side on Material Preview mode.

[image: comparison]

In this example I'm using Circle Mesh and scatter them using *Vector Wiggle*, however you can use particle system as well. The node setup is pretty much same as Omar's, use *Combine Mesh* to generate the polygons.

[image: node setup]

To generate edges we can use *Find Close Points* node (Mesh > Operators > Find Close Points), use mode Amount or Distance whichever that suit your need.

Here's the final result rendered using Viewport Render. https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZaAT3.jpg
. I use three *Find Close Points* nodes setup with different parameter and different material.